# Parsing the separated "aussi grande"

Tags: grammaire, sens

I'm having trouble understanding the construct of this sentence.

"Pourquoi **l**'ont-ils construite **aussi grande** ?"

How is it different in meaning from this?

"Pourquoi ont-ils construit **une aussi grande ville** ?"

Answer (score 1):

Considering in your first sentence, `l'` refers to a city, it can be rephrased to `Pourquoi ont-ils construit cette ville aussi grande ?`. `l'` is a pronoun that replaces the noun `city`.

The difference in meaning with the second sentence is very tiny.

Depending on the context, there might be a nuance, the second one might be a more general question, sort of `Is it useful to build such a big city, in general?`, while the first one might be more specific, sort of `Is it useful for this city in particular to be so big?`. But I bet in most cases, both sentences will be actually equivalent.

Note: the question is not specific to French language, actually. The same one would apply in English between `Why did they build it so big?` / `Why did they build this city so big?` and `Why did they build such a big city?`

Comment: What was confusing to me was that, is "grande" in the first an adverb?

Comment: Nope, it is an adjective. In French, we call this syntax, `adjectif attribut du complément d'objet direct (COD)` and when the COD (complement, here `ville`) is replaced by a pronoun, the adjectif gets separated from its qualified name. Other examples : `Je trouve ce site utile` => `Je le trouve utile`.